# Are triggers fired during DDL statements?

Tags: oracle, triggers

Say you have a "on delete" trigger

1 What will happen when you fire a delete?

> Trigger will be fired and trigger body will be executed

1. What will happen when you fire a truncate?

> My guess - nothing will happen as truncate(DDL) and delete(DML) are totally different commands
>   
>   One more question: Triggers are not fired on DDL statements, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct
2. Trigger will not fire and you are right that no DML triggers should fire on DDL statements.

More information: http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands

Comment: as you mentioned "no DML triggers should fire on DDL statements"... i got a question based on this : does oracle pl/sql offers DDL triggers also ?

Comment: one more thing...the link u mentioned above says that "In case of TRUNCATE ,Trigger doesn't get fired.But in DML commands like DELETE .Trigger get fired."......when we talk of triggers...do we talk of DML triggers by default....plz do not mind....I am asking a lot...but the thing is I want to clarify myself of the concepts

Comment: @jain007, yes, when people talk of Oracle triggers they tend to refer to DML triggers as they are by far the most common triggers in use in most RDBMS systems.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct with your assertions in your question as @Eggi says.

In addition to his answer and the details given in his link, `TRUNCATE` will reset the Highwater Mark in your table whereas `DELETE` will not.

If your table changes in size by a large amount then this could be very pertinent.

From AskTom:

> The HWM is relevant since Oracle will scan all blocks under the HWM,
>   even when they contain no data, during a full scan. This will impact
>   the performance of a full scan¿especially if most of the blocks under
>   the HWM are empty. To see this, just create a table with 1,000,000
>   rows (or create any table with a large number of rows), and then
>   execute a SELECT COUNT(*) from this table. Now, DELETE every row in it
>   and you will find that the SELECT COUNT(*) takes just as long (or
>   longer, if you need to clean out the block! Refer to the 'Block
>   Cleanout' section of Chapter 9) to count 0 rows as it did to count
>   1,000,000. This is because Oracle is busy reading all of the blocks
>   below the HWM to see if they contain data. You should compare this to
>   what happens if you used TRUNCATE on the table instead of deleting
>   each individual row. TRUNCATE will reset the HWM of a table back to
>   'zero' and will truncate the associated indexes on the table as well.
>   If you plan on deleting every row in a table, TRUNCATE¿if it can be
>   used¿would be the method of choice for this reason.

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:492636200346818072

Hope it helps...

Comment: yup...this gives a altogether new stuff....HWM...is this can be set by DDL truncate or there are other sql commnads to reset the HWM to zero/or some specified value

Comment: one more question: do truncate command first drops the table and then re create the table..... ?

Comment: Here is a good link about the HWM from Tom Kyte: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:669044239081 and here is a link about resetting the HWM: https://sysdba.wordpress.com/2006/04/28/how-to-adjust-the-high-watermark-in-oracle-10g-alter-table-shrink/

Comment: In relation to your question about `TRUNCATE`: A truncate moves the High Water Mark of the table back to zero. No row-level locks are taken, no redo or rollback is generated. All extents bar the initial are de-allocated from the table (if you have MINEXTENTS set to anything other than 1, then that number of extents is retained rather than just the initial). By re-positioning the high water mark, they prevent reading of any table data, so they have the same effect as a delete, but without all the overhead.